# Trying to use BCRYPT

Tags: php, bcrypt

My registration page uses BCRYPT and hashes the password into the database perfectly, however I am struggling to verify the password in the login page.

Below is my code and my attempt of verifying the password, however when running it I encounter HTTP ERROR 500.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$username'";

if (!$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))

{
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else
{   
   $count=mysqli_num_rows($result); 
}

if($count==1)
{   
   $hash = .$row['Password'];   
   if (password_verify($passfromform, $hash)) 
    {
       echo 'Password is valid!';
    } 
    else
    {
       echo 'Invalid password.';
    }   
}

else 
{
   header("location:User Login.html");
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated as it's giving me a headache now trying to solve my stupid mistake. Thanks

Comment: What is this suppose to do `$hash = .$row['Password'];`?

Comment: Not a clue, im trying to store the row "Password" from my database into a variable

Comment: If you don't have a clue how can we possibly help you?

Comment: Updated the code to $hash = $row['Password']; the page loads now but nothing is being stored in $hash still

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `$row` variable is not created anywhere but you are attempting to read from it.

It looks like you forgot `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` somewhere before `$hash = .$row['Password'];`. And change `$hash = .$row['Password'];` to `$hash = $row['Password'];`.